# Seed redis snapshot to elasticache

Tags: redis, terraform, amazon-elasticache, amazon-efs

I have currently an Elasticache instance, I also have a redis snapshot (rdb file) stored on EFS.
I was wondering if there's a way to seed snapshot's data in Elasticache (directly from EFS)

I found this [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/APIReference/API_CreateCacheCluster.html), but not sure if we can load data directly from EFS using **SnapshotName** parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way directly use EFS for that purposes, but you can upload you snapshot to S3 instead and restore ElastiCache from that snapshot.

There is an option called `snapshot_name` in terraform you can use after that: [Terraform Resource - aws_elasticache_cluster](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/elasticache_cluster#snapshot_name)

Other reading: [ElastiCache Backups restoring](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/backups-restoring.html)